# Let $a \in \mathbb C$. In the space $(\mathbb C[x]_{2})^{*}$ there are three functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a \in \mathbb C$. In the space $(\mathbb C[x]_{2})^{*}$ there are three functionals: $$f_{1}^{*}(p)=p(0)+ap(1)$$ $$f_{2}^{*}(p)=p(1)-ap(0)$$ $$f_{3}^{*}(p)=p'(1)-p'(0)$$ (a)  For which values of parameter $ a$ this system is the basis of space $(\mathbb C[x]_{2})^{*}$ 
 (b)  Whether there are such polynomials $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3} \in \mathbb C[x]_2$ for $a = 0$ that $$f_{k}^{*}(f_{j})= \begin{cases} 1, k=j \\ 0,k \neq j ?\end{cases} $$ If exist you find coefficients $ \alpha _{1},  \alpha _{2},  \alpha  _{3} \in \mathbb C$ such that for polynomial $q(x)=x^{2}-3$: $$ q= \alpha _{1} f_{1} + \alpha _{2} f_{2}+\alpha _{3} f_{3}. $$

I understand it but for ordinary polynomials. However this task is really abstract for me - when I must use functionals and I completely don't know what can I do in this case. I know that you can talk me that I am looking for a ready solution but I really don't understand and I find any hint that could lead me to a solution because I do this task by a long time and I know that I cannot do it alone...

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you know that $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}[x]_2$. Then, the mappings defined as $$g_{k}^{*}(g_{j})= \begin{cases} 1, k=j \\ 0,k \neq j ?\end{cases}$$ are a basis of $(\mathbb{C}[x]_2)^*$. Any polynomial $p$ can be written as $$p = bx^2 + cx +d.$$ We then have

$$\begin{pmatrix} f_1^* (p) \\ f_2^* (p) \\ f_3^* (p) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1+a & a & a \\ 1-a & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} d \\ c \\ b \end{pmatrix},$$
or, equivalently 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} f_1^*  \\ f_2^*  \\ f_3^*  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1+a & a & a \\ 1-a & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} g_1^* \\ g_2^* \\ g_3^* \end{pmatrix}.$$
Now if you know that a linear transformation maps a basis to a basis if and only if it is invertible, that should give you a way to check a). For b), think about what the transpose of the matrix above does.